# Clicking a button with a chrome extension (ERROR/Not working)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, web-deployment

Hello I want to click a button multiple times when on a specific website. I have no idea whats wrong but maybe someone can help me out

```
function pay(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn--lg btn--full u-margin-b--xl js-place-order2 js-place-order-btn")[0].click();

}

if(window.location.href.includes("https://www.revolveclothing.fr/r/ReviewConfirm.jsp?enteraccount")){
     
          var sleep = setTimeout(pay, 50)

}
```

The element I am Clicking is the correct one since it works in the chrome console
I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `setTimeout`, the button will only be pressed once after 50ms is elapsed.

Assuming you want it to be pressed consistently every 50ms, you should change the `setTimeout` to `setInterval` like so:

```
var sleep = setInterval(pay, 50);
```